# C - In a function used to add a node to a linked list, should i pass the members one by one or an instance of the node struct?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

While developing a project in the C language, I ran into a problem I had never thought about before.
In this project, I am using a linked list to store data from companies.
I am using the following structure to represent those companies:

```
typedef struct company {
    int id[ID_DIGITS_NUM];
    int num_employees;
    char *name;
    char *service;
    char *address;
    char **reviews;
    char *additional_data;
    struct company *next;
} Company;
```

As you can see, this structure has a lot of members.
And then, as I was writing the function prototype, I realized that it looked like this:

```
Company* addCompany(Company *head, int[ID_DIGITS_NUM], int, char *, char *, char *, char **, char *);
```

I thought that this was unnecessarily lengthy and messy.
So I thought that maybe I could externally create an instance of Company outside this function, and then use that as an argument, instead of using the structure's members, one by one.
Something like this:

```
Company* addCompany(Company *head, Company company);
```

This seems more clean and concise. However, during my linked lists research, I never saw this approach in any of the examples online. In this specific scenario, what do you believe to be the best approach and why?

Comment: Closer to the second.  A linked list doesn't need to know the internals of what it is storing.  The linked list code can be made completely generic, accepting `void *` pointers, and then it can be re-used for any object.   Separate the linked list structure from the data it is storing.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798715/c-linked-list-is-it-possible-to-create-a-payload-independent-iterator-function

Comment: Should you buy a car or a cargo van? It depends on what you need it for. If it is a sizable structure where most of the fields will be unused or initialized to null, passing a whole structure is a waste. If all the fields will be filled in all the time, passing a whole structure may be fine. And you can customize the design: Create an add-to-linked-list function that takes a structure the caller allocates and passes a pointer to, to be kept in the linked list. (With this, the caller is not making a copy that is just wasted.) Then create additional routine(s) customized for the way(s) a node…

Comment: … is typically created. Eg.., `addNodeWithID` that takes just an ID parameter, allocates space for a structure, initializes the structure, and pass it to the above add-to-linked-list function.